# C++: Inputting & Outputting UTF-8 on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, cjk

I'm not familiar with Windows at all

I'm struggling to write a function which reads from a file containing Chinese characters & does some regex.

Roughly:

```cpp
std::ifstream t(input_file);
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << t.rdbuf();
std::string page_contents = buffer.str();

...

page_contents = std::regex_replace(page_contents, std::regex("([a-z]{3})你好"), "$1再见");
```

This works fine on Debian, but Windows can't seem to handle the Chinese characters in the file at all. **I'm cross-compiling from Debian using MXE** (mingw)

I did some further testing:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 1000);
#endif

std::cout << "你好" << std::endl;
```

And found that where Debian outputted "你好" (`E4 BD A0 E5 A5 BD`), Windows outputted "ä½ å¥½" (`C3 A4 C2 BD C2 A0 C3 A5 C2 A5 C2 BD`)

I'm completely at a loss for how to handle this. Thanks a million in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction

Comment: `E4 BD A0 E5 A5 BD` is the correct UTF-8 encoded form of `"你好"`. `C3 A4 C2 BD C2 A0 C3 A5 C2 A5 C2 BD` is what happens when the UTF-8 codeunits are upscaled as-is into UTF-16 codeunits (ie `E4` -> `E400`, `BD` -> `BD00`, etc) and then encoded into UTF-8.

Comment: You have non-ASCII characters in your string literals. Is your source code file encoded in UTF-8? Have you tried prefixing the string literals with `u8` to force them to UTF-8? Have you tried using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`? You should be able to read a UTF-8 file with a `std::wifstream` if you `imbue()` a UTF-8 `std::locale` into the stream.